# Cannot add directory names ending in .el with normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path

Tags: load-path

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path<kbd>RET</kbd> gives:

> **(normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)**
>
> Recursively add all subdirectories of ‘default-directory’ to
>   ‘load-path’. More precisely, this uses only the subdirectories whose
>   names start with letters or digits; it excludes any subdirectory named
>   ‘RCS’ or ‘CVS’, and any subdirectory that contains a file named
>   ‘.nosearch’.

I am trying to use the package [`f`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) which has prerequisites the packages [`s`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) and 
[`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el). I want to load `f.el` with [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), so I downloaded the four packages with `git` into a custom folder: `~/.emacs.d/installed-from-github/`.

I recognized that after cloning with `git` the folder names of the first three packages became `dash.el`, `s.el`, and `f.el`. Note that each folder name contains a dot. But according to the documentation for `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` given above it should work for these type of directory names. However,
 when I try to run `emacs` with the following init file:

```
(setq debug-on-error t)
(let ((default-directory  "~/.emacs.d/installed-from-github/"))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
(message "%S" load-path)
(require 'use-package)
(use-package dash
  :demand)
(use-package s
  :demand)
(use-package f
  :demand)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load dash
```

and when I inspect the `*Messages*` buffer I can see that `load-path` does not contain any of `"/home/hakon/.emacs.d/installed-from-github/dash.el"`, `"/home/hakon/.emacs.d/installed-from-github/s.el"`, or `"/home/hakon/.emacs.d/installed-from-github/f.el"`.

Also, since if I change the directory name of `dash.el` to `dash-el` it seems to work fine, I suspect the problem is with the dot in the directory name.

Comment: `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` excludes all directories that match `\\.elc?\\'', which includes your directories. I'd say that's a bug in emacs, I can't think of a good reason not to allow it.

Comment: @RobertPluim Thanks for the comment, I have reported it as [bug#32266: Cannot add directory names ending in .el with normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2018-07/msg00877.html)